# Calling a function in android activity in AS3 native extensions

Tags: android, actionscript-3, adobe-native-extensions

I have an android ANE, and when the ANE initializes I start a new CustomActivity (extends Activity) which has all my custom logic for the ANE.

This is how I start the activity in my CustomExtensionContext (extends FREContext) class :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), CustomActivity.class);
getActivity().startActivity(intent);
```

Now, in my CustomAcivity, I have some other public methods which I want to call through my as3 code. I have created FREFunction classes and have added these functions to the HashMap. And I know how I can call the function from the as3 side.

What i dont know is, how to call some public method of CustomActivity class from my CustomExtensionContext, as I dont have any reference to its object ??!!

(new to Android, I am an AS3 developer)

Thanks

Comment: Any progress on this? You should share your solution. I personally don't think it's possible to access the functions of an Intent simply because Intents don't work that way (ie: they are just a step towards a final goal like the intention to access device's Photo Gallery where your goal is to load a picture back into your own app)...

Answer (score 0):

Technically I dont think this is the right answer, BUT this is how I solved my problem of accessing public function of the CustomActivity class.

I created a public static instance variable in the CustomActivity class of type CustomActivity and called

```
myStaticCustomActivityInstance = this;
```

in the onCreate and onResume function.

Then where ever I want access to this class's functions I can simply type :

```
if(CustomActivity.myStaticCustomActivityInstance != null)
{
    CustomActivity.myStaticCustomActivityInstance.somePublicFunction();
}
```